# Getting a build error in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am getting a weird C3681 error, keeps saying that an identifier cannot be found for one of my functions. I am very confused and have tried solutions found while using Google, but I cannot get it resolved. I would prefer not to use stl.

The error:

Error   1   error C3861: 'readTheStuff': identifier not found   c:\users\xxxxxx\desktop\data structures\homework2\homework2\editor.cpp  38  1   Homework2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int readFile(const char *fileName) {
    ifstream myReadFile;
    string line;
    int i = 0;
    myReadFile.open(fileName);
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            getline(myReadFile, line);
            line += " "; //adds a space after every line
            //cout << line << endl;
            readTheStuff(line);
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}

void readTheStuff(string command){
    cout << command; //testing
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){ //when they call, going to pass two parameters
    if (argc > 2){
        cout << "Error, more than one file given" << endl;
    }
    else if (argc < 2){
        cout << "Error, no file given" << endl;
    }
    else if (argc == 2){
        readFile(argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare a function before you can call it. Either make a declaration of `readTheStuff` before `readFile` or, more simply, just move the whole function up above `readFile`

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to fix this. 
1.) Include the following line just underneath your #includes in editor.cpp

void readTheStuff(std::string command)

or include the following line in addition to your other #includes

```
#include "editor.h"
```

inside editor.h the following line would need to appear

```
void readTheStuff(string command)
```

This is called prototyping and allows the compiler to link `readTheStuff(line)` to the actual function `reaTheStuff(string command).`